# Is this layout possible in Jasper 3.7 or any newer version ? Please advise

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to design a report that has the layout as attached below in the image. However, I cannot get to move the bands the way I want them to be. As a desperation, I tried forcing the 'detail' band in between the 'group header' and 'group footer' band but that gave a parsing problem. Now, I'm wondering even if it is possible to design the layout I want using iReport. Any suggestions would help or a blunt layout is not possible in iReport would help me save time I'm wasting on this. Thank you.

Oops...can't post images as I'm a first time user...but below is the lay out I'm trying to produce in iReport

```
[Group Header 1]
[Detail 1]
[Group Footer 1]
[Group Header 2]
[Detail 2]
[Group Footer 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with two sub-reports

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Kedar. I forgot to mention about the grouping I have. Below is an example of my report I'm building for a football league. The grouping is based on Team Name. For each team it would output Team Details, Team Summary, Goals for Detail and Fouls Against Detail and then move to do the same thing for the next team. Hope this clarifies what I'm trying to achieve. 
Subreport would essentially disrupt this grouping for me.

Below is the layout I'm trying to achieve.

http://pastebin.com/MxQ5M0jP

Comment: you can do three subreports.. one for Team Details (First Name,Last Name,Position), Goals for, and Fouls against. and pass the lists of names, goals and fouls respectively to the subreports. the main report will then have team name, and other summary fields

Comment: @Kedar, your total content is great. It would be better to move the comments into the answer so that everything is in one place.